# C# Interop.Outlook: Folder.AddToPFFavorites() without adding all subfolders?

Tags: c#, outlook, subdirectory, favorites

In Outlook, I'm trying to add a shared public folder (provided by Exchange) to the list of favorite folders programmatically.
I've written an Outlook-AddIn for this, that uses the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library. In this library, there's only one way to add public folders to the favorite list:

```
Folder.AddToPFFavorites().
```

The problem: When calling this method, Outlook not only adds the folder itself to the favorites list, but also ALL subfolders. In our company, we have a huge tree of subfolders attached to some folders, so I get major performance problems (Outlook completely crashes when the folder to add has too many subfolders).

Do you know a way to programmatically add only the folder itself to the favorites, without any subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You have to use the [AddToPFFavorites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869286(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Folder class.